# How would I loop this animation?

Tags: html, css, loops, web, animation

```
.rotatingText {
  font-family: "Georgia", serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.rotatingText-adjective {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 0;
}

.rotatingText-adjective:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.rotatingText-adjective:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.75s;
}

.rotatingText-adjective:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-name: rotate-last;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  }
  
  20%, 80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-last {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  }
  
    50%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

This is my code, I need this animation to loop, but if I put it in @keyframes, it doesn't do anything, and if I put it in rotating-adjective:nthOftype(x) it just makes the text overlap each other. Can someone help me, and if possible provide an example?

p.s i know i have to use animation-iteration-count: infinite;

Comment: Add some ```html``` to your question, to better understand.

Comment: The code you provided does not allow us to re-produce your issue and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your css and the animation will loop infinite times.

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```